# Ubuntu Server 18.04 two NIC on same subnet

Tags: ubuntu, routing, nic, netplan

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 with 2 NIC cards installed and both of them have static IP assigned via `netplan`.

This is my config:

```
root@box2:/etc/netplan# cat 01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: [192.168.0.11/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [62.179.1.60,8.8.8.8]
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
      - from: 192.168.0.11        
        on-link: true
        to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 100
    eno2:
      addresses: [192.168.0.12/24]
      # gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [62.179.1.60,8.8.8.8]
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
      - from: 192.168.0.12
        on-link: true
        to:  0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.0.1
        metric: 1000
```

---

```
root@box2:/etc/netplan# ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto static src 192.168.0.11 metric 100 onlink 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno2 proto static src 192.168.0.12 metric 1000 onlink 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.12 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.11
```

---

```
root@box2:/etc/netplan# sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.conf.*.arp
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno2.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
```

`ping` is working correctly on internal network from both IPs.

What is not working is ping to outside on `eno1` interface. I suspect that it has something to do with routing.

My primary goal is to have `eno1` interface as primary for all traffic and `eno2` as additional - both with internet access.

Comment: Why do you believe the problem is with your setup?